# Access dictionary of lists with sorting havin defaults filled

Tags: python, dictionary

I have created following dict `accs`:

```
{
'192.168.20.222': [('access_times', 10), ('bytes', 13147), ('errors', 20)], 
'192.168.60.200': [('access_times', 15), ('bytes', 118922), ('errors', 10)], 
'192.168.60.150': [('access_times', 20), ('bytes', 117989), ('errors', 30)],
'192.168.60.100': [('access_times', 40), ('bytes', 134922), ('errors', 15)],
...
}
```

How do I access it to retrieve a report for IP with biggest access_times count? / biggest bytes count, etc?

Here is the code that generates the dict:

```
accs = defaultdict(list)        
for i in reqs_host.keys():
        if reqs_host[i] > max_requests: 
            accs[i].append(('access_times', reqs_host[i]))
        if bytes_host[i] > max_bytes:
            accs[i].append(('bytes', bytes_host[i]))
        if errors_host[i] > max_errors:
            accs[i].append(('errors', errors_host[i]))
    #
    print dict(accs)
```

In case that some of the IFs don't get executed (i.e. `errors_host > max_errors`, but `reqs_hosts < max_reqests`) how can I still have `('access_times', X)` in the corresponding dict? So, have defaults in place.

Comment: What should your output look like?

Comment: something like:

   `Host 192.168.60.100 accessed: 40 times.

Host 192.168.60.150 accessed: 20 times.

   Host 192.168.60.200 accessed: 15 times.

   Host 192.168.20.222 accessed: 10 times.`

Comment: What is k? Why do you use such a horrible data format? The content of each entry is either a named tuple or a dict but not a list of tuples.

Comment: @Daniel - I don't think you should use the term 'horrible' while suggesting someone.

Comment: @Daniel, probably I just didn't find data format that better suits my needs yet, any suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always have the same attributes per entry, i would suggest the use of named tuples. That way, you can access the value by name, but don't have to store the name with each value.
To answer your question: you have to put the default value into the list on your own.

```
from collections import namedtuple

HostInfo = namedtuple('HostInfo', 'access_times,bytes,errors')

accs = {}
for i in reqs_host.keys():
    accs[i] = HostInfo(
        reqs_host[i] if reqs_host[i] > max_requests else None,
        bytes_host[i] if bytes_host[i] > max_bytes else None,
        errors_host[i] if errors_host[i] > max_errors else None
    )

for access_times, host in sorted((
            (info.access_times, host)
            for host, info in accs.iteritems()
            if info.access_times is not None
        ), reverse=True):
    print "Host %s accessed %s times"%(host, access_times)
```

Comment: sorry, the order in the sorting tuples is the important part. code corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as:

```
new_list = [(key,value[0][1]) for key,value in a.items()]

new_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for i in new_list:
    print 'Host',i[0],'accessed:',i[1],'times'

[OUTPUT]
Host 192.168.60.100 accessed: 40 times
Host 192.168.60.150 accessed: 20 times
Host 192.168.60.200 accessed: 15 times
Host 192.168.20.222 accessed: 10 times

>>> print new_list
[('192.168.60.100', 40),
 ('192.168.60.150', 20),
 ('192.168.60.200', 15),
 ('192.168.20.222', 10)]
```

Demo: http://repl.it/Rcp

Comment: Thanks, that solves the access and sort problem, still need to have default structure to sort properly. And some brainstorming to fully understand the code you've provided.

Comment: yes, if you don't mind and have any idea how to have sort the dict in case when `access_times` are missing from the entry, I think we need to have defaults, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @user2606078, You mean the `access_times` are zero?

Comment: not zero, but not present, if you look at the code that generate the dict, you'll see that if `access_time` are less that some predifined amount it doesn't get appended at all. That spoils the sorting...

Comment: @user2606078, I have updated the demo as follows: http://repl.it/Rcp/1. Tell me if that is what you want

Comment: @user2606078, It sets the default value is 0.